# How can objects have class methods in ruby?

Tags: ruby, object, module, class-method

Object , Class, Module , NilClass are all instances of Class.

1) First Doubt how can something be an instance of itself ? `(i.e 'Class' is an instance of 'Class')` or is my assumption wrong ?

2) If Object , Class ,Module etc ... are all objects then how can they have class methods ? Because class methods can only be called from classes and are not present in objects. `(or is my assertion incorrect that Object, Class , Module are all objects ?)`

3)If Object , Class , Module are not objects then what are they ?

3) Does a class method account for the missing method in instance `a` of `Class` and ultimately a decrease in method count ?

```
>> Class.methods.count

=> 82

>> a = Class.new

=> #<Class:0x1005519b8>

>> a.methods.count

=> 81
```

Comment: Maybe it's better to ask one answer at time.

Comment: FYI You can easily find out which methods differ between `Class.methods` and `Class.new.methods`: `Class.methods - Class.new.methods => ["nesting"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class objects *are* indeed objects.

Class methods are actually methods defined in the class's eigenclass (singleton class). That is why those methods are not available to actual instances of said classes.

Here's a way to help you see this: first, add a `singleton_class` method if you don't already have it:

```
module Kernel
  def singleton_class
    class << self
      self
    end
  end
end
```

Now, try the following:

```
String.instance_methods
String.singleton_class.instance_methods
Class.instance_methods
Class.singleton_class.instance_methods
c = Class.new
c.instance_methods
c.singleton_class.instance_methods
```

This will help you gain an appreciation for what methods are available to *instances* of a class, versus what methods are methods on the class (i.e., instances of the class's singleton class).

(You can pass a `false` argument to each of those `instance_methods` calls to see which methods are defined for that class, and not any superclasses.)

Comment: OK now here's as answer i was looking for ... i have been onto this for days now .. been asking a similar question on stack overflow for days, and people have been ridiculing and twisting and seem to be not getting it. I  get it now. Thank-you very much Chris. :)

Comment: I'm glad to be of help. I vastly prefer the name "eigenclass" also, but I've been overruled: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505067/class-self-idiom-in-ruby/2505077#2505077 and its attached comments. :-)

Comment: This is very close and now i know what i have to look for further (i.e eigenclass)

Answer (score 0):

1. The Ruby core is composed by `Class`, `Object`, `Module` and `Kernel`. They're predefined, so the `Class` class can be an instance of itself.
2. They have class methods because they're classes, too (and classes are objects).
3. I can't answer it yet. I have to discover which method is missing to think in an answer.

Comment: And `Kernel#method_missing` won't help me on answer 3. :)

Comment: Following method is missing : `Class.methods - a.methods` => `["nesting"]`

Comment: `Kernel#method_missing` why do i get this joke every-time and still i dont get it.