# How do you pass arguments to class << self in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, self

How do you pass arguments to `class << self` in Ruby? I have a snippet I'm working with below and I am trying to generate a picture using RMagick.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
%w[ rubygems RMagick ].each{|l| require l  }
%w[ Magick ].each{|i| require i }

module ImgGen
  class << self
    def start
      stripes = ImageList.new
      puts "hi"
    end

  end
end

WIDTH=650
HEIGHT=40
FILENAME="output.png"
FONT="winvga1.ttf"
ImgGen.start(WIDTH, HEIGHT, FILENAME, FONT)
```

Answer (score 5):

The arguments don't get passed to `class << self`, they get passed to the method:

```
module ImgGen
  class << self
    def start(width, height, filename, font)
      stripes = ImageList.new
      puts "hi"
    end
  end
end
```

You can read a [detailed description of what `class << self` does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505067/class-self-idiom-in-ruby) if it confuses you, but in short: it opens up the class's singleton class so you can add methods to it.