# Adding non-self rails method to Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want a method within

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def global_user_id
    User.find_by_username("Global_User").id
  end
end
```

which returns the current global user ID. I want it to be run using `User.global_user_id` rather than something like `User.new.global_user_id`

How would I do this?

I'm needing the user ID in other models and right now its stuck in class resources which I dont think is the best spot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is the `self.` in the name, it means that this function is a static one tied to the class and not to an instance of it.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.global_user_id
    find_by_username("Global_User").id
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! All comes back to me now... as a sidenote I thought I could do def global_user_id < self, or < User, but those dont seem to work. is this a special case or something?

Comment: In which case you don't need `User.` in the method call either, since you're already in the correct scope.

Comment: @Tallboy Methods can't "inherit" from a class, which is what it looks like you're trying to do there. You can do `class << self; def global_user_id; ... end; end` though. See [`class << self` idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2505067/211563).