# Declaring a class within a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, class

Surveying work code (in a module called Surveyor, no less), trying to understand it. I ran across this section that contains a class within a module. Is this the same as including the module? If not, what is the advantage of doing it this way? Thanks. (BONUS POINTS: Why are we appending self to class, is that not already implied?)

```
module Surveyor
  class Common
    RAND_CHARS = [('a'..'z'), ('A'..'Z'), (0..9)].map{|r| r.to_a}.flatten.join
    OPERATORS = %w(== != < > <= >= =~)

    class << self
      def make_tiny_code(len = 10)
        if RUBY_VERSION < "1.8.7"
          (1..len).to_a.map{|i| RAND_CHARS[rand(RAND_CHARS.size), 1] }.join
        else
          len.times.map{|i| RAND_CHARS[rand(RAND_CHARS.size), 1] }.join
        end
      end

      def to_normalized_string(text)
        words_to_omit = %w(a be but has have in is it of on or the to when)
        col_text = text.to_s.gsub(/(<[^>]*>)|\n|\t/su, ' ') # Remove html tags
        col_text.downcase!                            # Remove capitalization
        col_text.gsub!(/\"|\'/u, '')                   # Remove potential problem characters
        col_text.gsub!(/\(.*?\)/u,'')                  # Remove text inside parens
        col_text.gsub!(/\W/u, ' ')                     # Remove all other non-word characters      
        cols = (col_text.split(' ') - words_to_omit)
        (cols.size > 5 ? cols[-5..-1] : cols).join("_")
      end

      def equal_json_excluding_wildcards(a,b)
        return false if a.nil? or b.nil?
        a = a.is_a?(String) ? JSON.load(a) : JSON.load(a.to_json)
        b = b.is_a?(String) ? JSON.load(b) : JSON.load(b.to_json)
        deep_compare_excluding_wildcards(a,b)
      end
      def deep_compare_excluding_wildcards(a,b)
        return false if a.class != b.class
        if a.is_a?(Hash)
          return false if a.size != b.size
          a.each do |k,v|
            return false if deep_compare_excluding_wildcards(v,b[k]) == false
          end
        elsif a.is_a?(Array)
          return false if a.size != b.size
          a.each_with_index{|e,i| return false if deep_compare_excluding_wildcards(e,b[i]) == false }
        else
          return (a == "*") || (b == "*") || (a == b)
        end
        true
      end

      alias :normalize :to_normalized_string

      def generate_api_id
        UUIDTools::UUID.random_create.to_s
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> what is the advantage of doing it this way?

It serves as [namespace](https://practicingruby.com/articles/uses-for-modules-1) so classes with the same name do not clash (so it has nothing to do with mixins). It's standard.

> Why are we appending self to class, is that not already implied?

That's just one of the ways of [defining class-methods](http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/10/ruby-defining-class-methods.html) (the other being `def self.method_name`).

Answer (score 11):

> Is this the same as including the module?

No. When you have `module Foo; end` and then do

```
class Bar
  include Foo
end
```

You end up with a class `Bar` that includes all the methods of the module `Foo`. But when we do

```
module Foo
  class Bar
  end
end
```

We end up with a class `Foo::Bar` that includes none of the methods in `Foo` that are not in `Bar`

> What is the advantage of doing it this way?

It allows your to organize your code, if it's needed.

> Why are we appending self to class, is that not already implied?

No, it's not already "implied". Doing so is equivalent to defining each method in that block with `self.` like `def self.mymethod; end`. See [class << self idiom in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505067/class-self-idiom-in-ruby).