# What is << in this context?

Tags: ruby, class, metaclass

I'm working on this tutorial here:
http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/39-ruby-s-object-model/lessons/131-singleton-methods-and-metaclasses

The lesson is on classes/metaclasses, but they are using a syntax that I'm not familiar with. Please see the use of << below

```
class Object
  def metaclass
    class << self
      self
    end
  end
end


a=Object.new
p a.metaclass.new
```

I know `def metaclass` is a method, but what is meant by `class << self`? It has a corresponding `end` block, but I'm still very unclear what this is exactly doing

(Note: The point of the above exercise is just showing that you cannot instantiate a metaclass -- which I understand, I'm just having trouble wrapping my head around that << operator in this context.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2505077/16959 `<<` this should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class << self` opens up `self`'s singleton class, so that methods can be redefined for the current `self` object.

Let's look at a particular example:

```
 s = String.new("abc")
 s.metaclass
   => "#<Class:#<String:0x0000010117e5d8>>"
```

Let's have a closer look at what happens here:

- Inside the definition of `metaclass`, `self` refers to the current instance, in this example the string "abc".
- `class << self` in this example is equivalent to `class << "abc"` which opens up the singleton-class of that given instance , in this case String "abc".
- It then returns `self` inside the opened-up class of the current instance -- the opened-up class is in the example the class `String`.

In general, the definition of `metaclass` opens up the class definition of the class of the given instance/object, and then returns that class name.

A more detailed look at 'self' can be found in Yehuda Katz's article "[Metaprogramming in Ruby: It’s All About the Self](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/15/metaprogramming-in-ruby-its-all-about-the-self/)".

I also recommend the screen-cast series by the [Pragmatic Programmers on The Ruby Object Model and Metaprogramming](http://pragprog.com/screencasts/v-dtrubyom/the-ruby-object-model-and-metaprogramming).