# leap.rb cant find modulo error

Tags: ruby

Wondering if anyone can see why I cant call .modulo. I feel like its something like I have to call Math in the class but I Im not sure thats the case.

git: https://github.com/jbasalone/ja/tree/master/ruby/exercism.io/leap

the error:

```
test_leap_year(YearTest):
    NoMethodError: undefined method `modulo' for nil:NilClass
    /Users/jennyb/ja/ja/ruby/exercism.io/leap/year.rb:26:in `divbyfour?'
    /Users/jennyb/ja/ja/ruby/exercism.io/leap/year.rb:17:in `leap?'
    leap_test.rb:6:in `test_leap_year'
```

This is my code:

```
class Year

    def initialize(theyear)
        @theyear = theyear
    end
class << self

    attr_reader :theyear

    def initialize(theyear)
        @theyear = theyear
    end

    def leap?(theyear)
        divbyfour? && !acentury? || bcentury?
    end
    #private

    def acentury?
        theyear.modulo 100 == 0
    end

    def divbyfour?
        theyear.modulo 4 == 0
    end

    def bcentury?
        theyear.modulo 400 == 0 
    end
    end
    end
```

And this is the test I run against it:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require_relative 'year'

class YearTest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
   def test_leap_year
     assert Year.leap?(1996)
   end

  def test_non_leap_year
    skip
    refute Year.leap?(1997)
  end

  def test_non_leap_even_year
    skip
    refute Year.leap?(1998)
  end

  def test_century
    skip
    refute Year.leap?(1900)
  end

  def test_fourth_century
    skip
    assert Year.leap?(2400)
  end
end
```

Comment: You don't initialize the Year class:

Year.new(1996).leap?

also you don't need arguments for leap? method:

    def leap?(theyear)
        divbyfour? && !acentury? || bcentury?
    end

should be changed to 

    def leap?
        divbyfour? && !acentury? || bcentury?
    end

Comment: if I remove the the arguement I get; test_leap_year(YearTest):
    ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
    /Users/jennyb/code/training/ruby/leap/year.rb:21:in `leap?'
    leap_test.rb:6:in `test_leap_year'

Comment: Sorry my comment wasn't too clear, I posted an answer below, that worked for me. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
class Year

    attr_accessor :theyear

    def initialize(theyear)
        @theyear = theyear
    end

    def leap?
        divbyfour? && !acentury? || bcentury?
    end
    #private

    def acentury?
        theyear.modulo(100) == 0
    end

    def divbyfour?
        theyear.modulo(4) == 0
    end

    def bcentury?
        theyear.modulo(400) == 0 
    end
end
```

And then you call it with:

```
y = Year.new(1995)
y.leap?
```

Alternatively you can use it like this:

```
class Year

    def self.leap?(year)
        @theyear = year
        divbyfour? && !acentury? || bcentury?
    end

    def self.theyear
      @theyear
    end
    #private

    def self.acentury?
        theyear.modulo(100) == 0
    end

    def self.divbyfour?
        theyear.modulo(4) == 0
    end

    def self.bcentury?
        theyear.modulo(400) == 0 
    end
end
```

And then you don't need to initialize the Year class.

```
Year.leap?(1995)
=> false
```

Comment: yea youd think that would work. Thats how I had it originally but the test expects a class method

Comment: Nice. It brought on something new but it progressed.  1) Error:
test_leap_year(YearTest):
TypeError: false can't be coerced into Fixnum
    /Users/jennyb/code/training/ruby/leap/year.rb:23:in `modulo'
    /Users/jennyb/code/training/ruby/leap/year.rb:23:in `divbyfour?'
    /Users/jennyb/code/training/ruby/leap/year.rb:10:in `leap?'
    leap_test.rb:6:in `test_leap_year'

Comment: You probably didn't change the modulo method like this:

theyear.modulo(4) == 0 

It needs the parentheses in order to work. The error you receive is the one I got when I tried it without parentheses.

Comment: I used theyear.modulo(100).zero? cause I thought it was sexier. Thanks!

Comment: Hehe nice :-) Glad I was of help!

Answer (score 0):

In `divbyfour` method you call `modulo` on `theyear` variable which doesn't exist.

Here's a code that fixes your problem.

```
class Year
  attr_reader :theyear

  def initialize(theyear)
    @theyear = theyear
  end

  def leap?
    divbyfour? && !acentury? || bcentury?
  end

  def acentury?
    theyear.modulo(100) == 0
  end

  def divbyfour?
    theyear.modulo(4) == 0
  end

  def bcentury?
    theyear.modulo(400) == 0
  end
end
```

Example:

```
>> year = Year.new 2014
=> #<Year:0xb8eb15b4 @theyear=2014>
>> year.leap?
=> false
```

What I did:

- Removed `include Math`. [`Math` doesn't implement `modulo` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Math.html), so it's not required here, you don't need it anyway – `Fixnum` [implements its own `modulo` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-modulo).
- Removed `class << self` line. [Read up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505067/class-self-idiom-in-ruby) on what it does. Also, `initialize` should be an instance method, not a class one. Here's a good post on [differences between instance and class methods in Ruby](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/).
- Added parentheses in calls to `modulo`. `theyear.modulo 100 == 0` is an equivalent to `theyear.modulo(100 == 0)` and what you actually want is `theyear.modulo(100) == 0`.

If you have time, check out [Ruby Koans](http://rubykoans.com/) – it's a great way to learn Ruby and its idioms.

Comment: That wont work because the test is expecting a class method, not an instance method.

Comment: Did you write this test by yourself? IMHO from OOP point of view it makes much more sense for `leap?` to be an instance method, not a class method.

Comment: I did not, it didn't make much sense to me