# Requesting insight on ruby code

Tags: ruby

My team has been reading existing ruby code to build our understanding.  We commonly find things we don't quite understand, even with research.  Please comment on the following questions.

### Question 1

For the following code, why is `class << self` defined right under the module name?  Does that imply defining a class with the module name?

```
module GravatarImageTag

  class << self
    attr_accessor :configuration
  end
```

### Question 2

Why does the author define `class << self` and go on to define methods with `self.`?  Our understanding is thay you can define `self.` methods in a block that starts with `class << self` rather than repeat `self.` for each method.

```
module GravatarImageTag

  class << self
    attr_accessor :configuration
  end

  def self.configuration
    @configuration ||= Configuration.new
  end

  def self.configure
    yield(configuration)
  end
```

### Question 3

Why does the author use the class name rather than self in the method `self.include(base)`?  Furthermore, with this file's structure, what is class is `self.include(base)` a member of?  This relates to question 1.

```
module GravatarImageTag

  class << self
    attr_accessor :configuration
  end

  def self.configuration
    @configuration ||= Configuration.new
  end

  def self.configure
    yield(configuration)
  end

  class Configuration
     attr_accessor :default_image, :filetype, :include_size_attributes,
       :rating, :size, :secure

     def initialize
        @include_size_attributes = true
     end
  end

  def self.included(base)
    GravatarImageTag.configure { |c| nil }
    base.extend ClassMethods
    base.send :include, InstanceMethods
  end
```

Thanks.

Comment: @sawa I was going to comment something similar, but then realized that these questions do seem closely tied to each other and may not be very easy to separate. Idk though...

Comment: @Ajedi32 I understand what you mean, but overall, it is too long. It needs to be either more concise, or separated.

Comment: Related: [class << self idiom in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505067/class-self-idiom-in-ruby), [Module#included](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Module.html#method-i-included)

Answer (score 0):

**Little Bit Explanation:**

`class << self` is more than just a way of declaring class methods (though it can be used that way). Probably you've seen some usage like:

```
class Foo
  class << self
    def a
      print "I could also have been defined as def Foo.a."
    end
  end
end
```

This works, and is equivalent to `def Foo.a`, but the way it works is a little subtle. The secret is that `self`, in that context, refers to the object `Foo`, whose class is a unique, anonymous subclass of `Class`. This subclass is called `Foo`'s eigenclass. So `def a` creates a new method called a in `Foo`'s eigenclass, accessible by the normal method call syntax: `Foo.a`.

Now let's look at a different example:

```
str = "abc"
other_str = "def"

class << str
  def frob
    return self + "d"
  end
end

print str.frob # => "abcd"
print other_str.frob # => raises an exception, 'frob' is not defined on other_str
```

This example is the same as the last one, though it may be hard to tell at first. `frob` is defined, not on the `String` class, but on the eigenclass of `str`, a unique anonymous subclass of `String`. So `str` has a `frob` method, but instances of `String` in general do not. We could also have overridden methods of `String` (very useful in certain tricky testing scenarios).

via David Seiler