# Why is `class << self` more common than `class << Foo` for opening a class object's eigenclass?

Tags: ruby, coding-style, eigenclass

Ruby programmers typically use [`class << self` inside a class body](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2505077/13) to open up the class object's eigenclass, like so:

```
class Foo
  class << self
    # ...
  end
end
```

However, I seldom see this equivalent form (assume that `Foo` is already defined to be a class):

```
class << Foo
  # ...
end
```

Is there a reason for preferring the first style to the second?

Comment: Stylistically, it makes the operation easier to see with a consistent idiom.

Comment: I expect the same answer would apply if you asked why class methods are generally defined `def self.a ... end`, rather than `def A.a ... end`.  In both cases, the use of `self` reduces by one the number of lines in your code that require attention if you rename the class.  I can't think of any other benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `class << Foo`, or when defining explicitly `def Foo.some_method(args)` you are repeating the name of the class.

Using `class << self` is DRYer, and makes refactoring easier (changing the class name is done in one place, and does not have to be repeated in the code), as well as copy+paste to other classes/projects.

```
class Foo1
  # ..
end

class << Foo # <- :(
  #..
end
```

Comment: There's no repetition in the OP's examples. Both mention `Foo` exactly once.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - from the OP `(assume that Foo is already defined to be a class)` - if it was not mentioned before you'd get `uninitialized constant Foo`

Comment: @JörgWMittag The OP says that the class is defined elsewhere for the second example. So if that (elsewhere-defined) class were ever renamed, you'd have to change the name in the second example.  Instead the first example, provided it's defined in the file where the class name is specified, wouldn't need to change.

Comment: Anyone who prefers using `def self.xyz` method over either solutions?

Comment: @UriAgassi What about the case where you're opening a class's eigenclass in a different file from where the class was defined? (e.g., monkey-patching a built-in class.) You don't get to escape naming the class in that case, so is there a benefit to still using `class Object; class << self` vs `class << Object`?

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young - I think in this case the most notable advantage for `class << self` is conformity - there is no point in using a less ubiquitous syntax because it saves a few characters, only to have it harder to read since it is less well-known.