# Ruby koan 248: What's the point I'm missing?

Tags: ruby

I've just completed Ruby koan 248 and toward the end of the about_class_methods,rb file there's this section of code:

```
class Dog
    def self.class_method2
      :another_way_to_write_class_methods
    end
  end

  def test_you_can_use_self_instead_of_an_explicit_reference_to_dog
    assert_equal :another_way_to_write_class_methods, Dog.class_method2
  end

  # ------------------------------------------------------------------

  class Dog
    class << self
      def another_class_method
        :still_another_way
      end
    end
  end

  def test_heres_still_another_way_to_write_class_methods
    assert_equal :still_another_way, Dog.another_class_method
  end

  # THINK ABOUT IT:
  #
  # The two major ways to write class methods are:
  #   class Demo
  #     def self.method
  #     end
  #
  #     class << self
  #       def class_methods
  #       end
  #     end
  #   end
  #
  # Which do you prefer and why?
  # Are there times you might prefer one over the other?
```

I'm not sure I appreciate why I might, in different circumstances, prefer one syntax over the other. I can see that you might be able to define a set of methods in the class << self section, but is THAT the point being made? I assume there's something subtle I'm missing, but I don't know what that is.

Would anyone mind spelling it out to me?

Comment: Here's a great answer on the topic http://stackoverflow.com/a/2505077/3109182

Comment: OK, I've read that and I get that `class << self` can be used to add static methods to a class. I don't see how that clears up the above question though - why should I prefer one syntax over another at times? Sorry, but I can either ask for a clearer explanation or hope that it's just not an important distinction and move on.

Comment: How would you ask Ruby to generate an attribute reader for an instance variable of the class?

Comment: I honestly don't know. I'm guessing with one syntax you can and the other you can't? Let me know if that's what you're implying. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `class << self` over `def self.method` because you might want to add an attribute reader property to the class. In fact, any time you want to use syntax defined for classes, you might want to consider `class << self`. I'm new to Ruby, but I imagine if you wanted to define many class methods you could group them all together using the `class << self` syntax.