# Creating a new class with an existing name

Tags: ruby

We can create a class and then create another class with the same name. That is not surprising.

```
[1] pry(main)> class A; end
=> nil
[2] pry(main)> a = A.new
=> #<A:0x0000000bd8a008>
[3] pry(main)> A = Class.new
(pry):3: warning: already initialized constant A
(pry):1: warning: previous definition of A was here
=> A
[4] pry(main)> new_a = A.new
=> #<A:0x0000000be001e0>
[5] pry(main)> a.class.name == new_a.class.name
=> true
[6] pry(main)> a.class == new_a.class
=> false
[7] pry(main)> a.class == A
=> false
[8] pry(main)> new_a.class == A
=> true
```

However, after redefining the constant we get what seems to be a collision: constant `A` and `new_a.class`method return the new class, while `a.class` returns the original class. These classes are different, yet they have the same name. How can this be possible and what exactly is going on when this code is executed?

Comment: It’s the same situation like whether you have two “John Smith” entries in your phonebook. Eigenclasses differ. You might easily modify `a`’s eigenclass without overwriting constants (e.g. by opening and modifying it with [`class << self`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505067/class-self-idiom-in-ruby)) and an effect would be the same.

Comment: I don't see what it has to do with eigenclasses. The `singleton_class` method is not even used in this code. Can you explain in more details?

Comment: I put the example in the answer since it contains a lot of formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`class A; end` does two things:

1. it creates a new class object
2. it assigns this class object to the constant `A`

Removing or resassigning the constant only affects (2), it doesn't change the class object (1).

Ruby also sets the *class name* when assigning a class to a constant:

```
A.name #=> "A"
```

The class name is stored in a special instance variable (see below) and you see this name when inspecting an instance of your class:

```
A.new
#=> #<A:0x007febc1230848>
#     ^
#     |
#     +- this is A.name
```

The class name is independent of the constant a class is assigned to:

```
B = A

B.name #=> "A"
B.new  #=> #<A:0x007febc1313e68>
```

And this is why you can create multiple classes with the same name.

#### How the class name is stored internally

Ruby stores the class name in a special instance variable `__classpath__`. It can't be accessed from within Ruby, but if you would remove this restriction (I've patched Ruby for this example), you could read it:

```
A.instance_variable_get('__classpath__') #=> "A"
```

and even change it:

```
a = A.new #=> #<A:0x007fe0cd03ad30>
A.instance_variable_set('__classpath__', 'just a name')
A.name #=> "just a name"
a #=> #<just a name:0x007fe0cd03ad30>
```

Comment: Thank you. So, there is no way to get a class just by its name (besides using `ObjectSpace.each_object`) in Ruby. We can do that only via variables/constants etc. Am I correct?

Comment: Ruby assigns classes to constants because it's convenient. Regarding your initial question *"(...) they have the same name. How can this be possible (...) ?"* - I think once you understand that the class name is an attribute of the class object, it becomes obvious why two classes can have the same name.

Answer (score 2):

> These classes are different, yet they have the same name. How can this be possible and what exactly is going on when this code is executed?

It's perfectly possible for two different objects to return the same value when you call a certain method. There's really nothing sophisticated about that:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = 'AB'

a.size # => 2
b.size # => 2
```

Note that both `a` and `b` return `2` when I call `size`, but that does not imply any sort of relationship at all between `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

It’s the same like having two “John Smith” entries in your phonebook. Consider we have a class:

```
class A
  def whoami
    puts 'original'
  end
end
```

Let’s now instantiate it:

```
a = new A
a_frozen = new A
a.whoami
#⇒ original
a_frozen.whoami
#⇒ original
```

Let’s modify `a`’s eighenclass:

```
class << a
  def whoami
    'modified'
  end
end

a.whoami
#⇒ modified
a_frozen.whoami
#⇒ original
```

And, of course, it’s still like:

```
a.class.name == a_frozen.class.name == 'A'
```

Name is *the name only*, nothing more. And there is no problem for different class instances share the same name.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It does not at all. The code you've written does indeed add the 'whoami' method to the eigenclass, but I don't see how it is relevant to different classes having the same name, because `a` and `a_frozen` are instances of the same class and  `a.class == a_frozen.class` returns `true`. Oh, and by the way, name is not "just a name", it is a constant in Ruby. So we basically get two constants with the same name and different values. Hence my confusion.

Comment: No, we have _only one_ constant, of type `String`, containing string value `"A"`. My example shows how two instances of the same class might differ; I thought it would hint you how instances of two different classes might differ. It does not matter, that the names equal. Once an instance is created, it’s “operated” by it’s eigenclass and class name is just a nick for friends, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

`a` and `new_a` are instances of two different classes.
You can access these classes with `a.class` and `new_a.class`.
These classes are two instances of `Class`. They appear to have the same name they really are different classes, with different methods, etc.

```
class A
  def a
  end
end

a= A.new
A = Class.new
new_a = A.new

puts a.respond_to?(:a) # => true
puts new_a.respond_to?(:a) # => false
```

Comment: Yes, I agree. I wrote almost the same words, "These classes are different, yet they have the same name." But how exactly can this be possible and what exactly is going on when this code is executed? A class name is a constant. How is it possible for us to have two constants with different values?

Comment: Huh? A class name is not a constant, it is a string. And you don't have one constant with two values, you have two different objects which return the same value when you call a certain method. That's not really surprising at all. `[1, 2].size` and `'AB'.size` both return `2` but that doesn't mean that they are somehow the same.