# Ruby IO - File input/output indirectly

Tags: ruby, file

Recently I've been learning Ruby.I hit a problem while I'm writing a subclass of File.

```
class MyFile < File

end

file_path = "text_file"

file = MyFile.open(file_path) do | file |
    file.each_line do | line |
        puts line
    end
    file.close
end
```

result:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

If I want output by calling a method:

```
class MyFile < File
    def foo
        self.each_line do | line |
            puts line
        end
    end
end

file_path = "text_file"

my_file = MyFile.open(file_path) do | file |
    file.foo
    file.close
end
```

Result:

```
/Users/veightz/Developer/RubyCode/io_error.rb:4:in `write': not opened for writing (IOError)
    from /Users/veightz/Developer/RubyCode/io_error.rb:4:in `puts'
    from /Users/veightz/Developer/RubyCode/io_error.rb:4:in `block in foo'
    from /Users/veightz/Developer/RubyCode/io_error.rb:3:in `each_line'
    from /Users/veightz/Developer/RubyCode/io_error.rb:3:in `foo'
    from /Users/veightz/Developer/RubyCode/io_error.rb:20:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/veightz/Developer/RubyCode/io_error.rb:19:in `open'
    from /Users/veightz/Developer/RubyCode/io_error.rb:19:in `<main>'
```

Then I add new method `bar`

```
class MyFile < File
    def foo
        self.each_line do | line |
            puts line
        end
    end

    def bar
        self.each_line do | line |
            p line
        end
    end
end

my_file = MyFile.open(file_path) do | file |
    file.bar
    file.close
end
```

Result:

```
"line 1\n"
"line 2\n"
"line 3\n"
```

So, I'm so confused about IO in Ruby.Why `puts line` in `foo` can't work well.

Answer (score 6):

There is a [`puts` method in `IO`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-puts) and `IO` is a superclass of `File`. That means that this:

```
puts line
```

is actually `self.puts` rather than [`Kernel#puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) as it is pretty much everywhere else that you use `puts`. Hence the "not opened for writing" error message.

You need an explicit receiver to get the same effect as `Kernel#puts`; `Kernel#puts` is equivalent to `$stdout.puts` so you want:

```
file.each_line do | line |
  $stdout.puts line
end
```

Your `p line` version works fine because there is no `IO#p` or `File#p` method, `p` is [`Kernel#p`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-p) just like it is everywhere else.

Keep in mind that we don't have functions in Ruby the way other languages have global functions. Methods that you use like a function are almost always methods in `Kernel`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `$>` "the default output stream" to redirect output of methods such as Kernel#puts... Which is the sole job of  `$>` .

```
def foo
     self.each_line do | line |
     $>.puts line
     end
end
```

I added one more method showing how you can also borrow "require" other gems (e.g pretty-printed gem) and the use of `class << slef`....Hence , you said "Recently I've been learning Ruby" :|

**The below works as intended.**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'pp'

class MyFile < File
class << self

    def foo
        each_line do | line |
           $>.puts line
        end
    end



    def bar
        each_line do | line |
            p line
        end
    end


    def bam
     each_line do | line |
            pp line
        end
    end

end

file_path = "/Users/path/ofdirectory_to/somefile.txt"

my_file = MyFile.open(file_path) do | file |

    file.bam
    file.foo
    file.bar
    File.close
end
```

Note: the use of NameOfClass << self  ... wana read more [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505067/class-self-idiom-in-ruby)

What seems btter :

non-pretty-printed output by p is:

```
  #<PP:0x81fedf0 @genspace=#<Proc:0x81feda0>, @group_queue=#<PrettyPrint::GroupQueue:0x81fed3c @queue=[[#<PrettyPrint::Group:0x81fed78 @breakables=[], @depth=0, @break=false>], []]>, @buffer=[], @newline="\n", @group_stack=[#<PrettyPrint::Group:0x81fed78 @breakables=[], @depth=0, @break=false>], @buffer_width=0, @indent=0, @maxwidth=79, @output_width=2, @output=#<IO:0x8114ee4>>
```

pretty-printed output by pp is:

```
 #<PP:0x81fedf0
 @buffer=[],
 @buffer_width=0,
 @genspace=#<Proc:0x81feda0>,
 @group_queue=
  #<PrettyPrint::GroupQueue:0x81fed3c
   @queue=
    [[#<PrettyPrint::Group:0x81fed78 @break=false, @breakables=[], @depth=0>],
     []]>,
 @group_stack=
  [#<PrettyPrint::Group:0x81fed78 @break=false, @breakables=[], @depth=0>],
 @indent=0,
 @maxwidth=79,
 @newline="\n",
 @output=#<IO:0x8114ee4>,
 @output_width=2>
```

For more about pp go here [Ruby-Doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/pp/rdoc/PP.html)