# How does forwardable work in this context?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, rack

I'm following along a [tutorial to make a Rack-based app](https://book.buildyourownsinatra.com/chapters/building-your-framework.html):

```
require 'forwardable'
module Eldr
  class App
    class << self
      extend Forwardable
      attr_accessor :builder
      def_delegators :builder, :map, :use

      def builder
        @builder ||= Rack::Builder.new
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I know this will sound really noobish, but I'm new to Ruby metaprogramming:

- What exactly is the `class << self`? Doesnt that mean `App < App`?
- What exactly is [Forwardable](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html)? I looked it up but I'm sad to say I don't understand it still
- Why is app extending Forwardable and what is Forwardable?

I know that the goal is to make this bit behave like `Rack::Builder`; Just trying to wrap my head around this one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, if you have three questions, ask three questions, not one. For example, your question about `class << foo` has already been asked and answered on StackOverflow, but because of the other two questions with which it is intermingled, it cannot be linked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

> What exactly is the `class << self`? Doesnt that mean `App < App`?

No, the syntax `class << self` lets you modify the metaclass of an object (in this case `self`). There is a great answer that explains this here: [class << self idiom in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505067/class-self-idiom-in-ruby)

> What exactly is Forwardable? I looked it up but I'm sad to say I don't understand it still.

The `Forwardable` module allows methods send to one object to be redirected to the result of calling a method on that object. In this case, methods sent to `Eldr::App` will be redirected to `Eldr::App.builder`. So when you call `Eldr::App.map`, you are actually calling `Eldr::App.builder.map`.

> Why is app extending Forwardable?

The `extend Forwardable` line adds `Forwardable` to the list of ancestors of `Eldr::App`'s metaclass. This is done just because that's how forwardable was designed to be used. [Here is a link to Forwardable's documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html). It has some examples of what `Forwardable` is and how to use it.