# Alias module`s method in C(Ruby Extension)

Tags: c, ruby, marshalling, alias

I can`t alias method "dump" from Marshal module

```
#include "ruby.h"
VALUE Marshal = Qnil;
void Init_test(){
  Marshal = rb_define_module("Marshal");
  rb_define_alias(Marshal, "hal_dump", "dump");//No error, but don`t work
}
```

In ruby:

```
require './test'
p Marshal.methods.grep(/dump/).sort #[:dump]
```

How i can do alias?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your C code is similar to the following Ruby code:

```
module Marshal
  alias hal_dump dump
end
```

[`dump` is a singleton method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Marshal.html#method-c-dump) but also a private instance method (that combination is a so-called module function). You only define an alias of the private instance method.

```
p Marshal.private_instance_methods.grep(/dump/) # => [:dump, :hal_dump]
```

That's also why you don't get an error. However you want to define an alias of the singleton method. That can be done by [opening the singleton class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505067/class-self-idiom-in-ruby). A corrected Ruby version might look like this:

```
p Marshal.methods.grep(/dump/) # => [:dump]
class << Marshal
  alias hal_dump dump
end
p Marshal.methods.grep(/dump/) # => [:dump, :hal_dump]
```

The MRI C API implements the [`rb_singleton_class()`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_2/class.c#L1601-L1627) function. It returns the singleton class and can be used like this to fix your code:

```
rb_define_alias(rb_singleton_class(Marshal), "hal_dump", "dump");
```

Comment: `dump` is actually defined using `rb_define_module_function`, which defines a module (singleton) method _and_ a private instance method (otherwise you would get an error when trying to alias it). `p Marshal.private_instance_methods` should show it.

Comment: @matt: Thanks, I've missed that. I'll correct my answer soon.