# How to refine module method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0, ruby-2.1, ruby-2.2

You can refine your class with

```
module RefinedString
  refine String do
    def to_boolean(text)
    !!(text =~ /^(true|t|yes|y|1)$/i)
    end
  end
end
```

but how to refine module method? 
This:

```
module RefinedMath
  refine Math do
    def PI
      22/7
    end
  end
end
```

raises: `TypeError: wrong argument type Module (expected Class)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### This piece of code will work:

```
module Math
  def self.pi
    puts 'original method'
   end
end

module RefinementsInside
  refine Math.singleton_class do
    def pi
      puts 'refined method'
    end
  end
end

module Main
  using RefinementsInside
  Math.pi #=> refined method
end

Math.pi #=> original method
```

#### Explanation:

Defining a module **#method** is [equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33673263/3192470) to defining an instance method on its **#singleton_class**.

Answer (score 1):

> Refinements only modify classes, not modules so the argument must be a class.

— http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html

As soon as you are aware of what you are doing, you have two options to *refine* module methods globally. Since ruby has open classes, you might simply override the method:

```
▶ Math.exp 2
#⇒ 7.38905609893065
▶ module Math
▷   def self.exp arg
▷     Math::E ** arg
▷   end  
▷ end  
#⇒ :exp
▶ Math.exp 2
#⇒ 7.3890560989306495
```

Whether you want to save the functionality of the method to be overwritten:

```
▶ module Math
▷   class << self
▷     alias_method :_____exp, :exp  
▷     def exp arg  
▷       _____exp arg    
▷     end  
▷   end  
▷ end  
#⇒ Math
▶ Math.exp 2
#⇒ 7.3890560989306495
```

Please be aware of side effects.

Comment: So is there any way to _refine_ module's method?

Comment: At the time being there is no way to refine modules, as it clearly stated in the documentation I linked.

Comment: There might be other solution than using exactly `refine` method and this is what I'm seeking