# How to get class constant name in ruby

Tags: ruby, reflection

I need get constant name from this:

```
class Sex
    Male = 1
    Female = 2
end
```

But this is perfect variant, can i get constant name at least from this:

```
class Sex
    self.Male = 1
    self.Female = 2
end
```

Few details about the problem:

- You can get a list of methods: `Class.methods - Object.methods`
- You can get a list of instance variables: `instance_variables.map{|ivar| instance_variable_get ivar}`
- You can get a list of constant names from **Module**: `Module.constants`

But i have no idea how I can get *class* constant names.

Comment: Your second example is wrong. Do you mean `class Sex; class << self; Male = 1; Female = 2; end; end`?

Comment: I did not think about this way, but yes it will be like u wrote. Anyway, it is not answer.

Comment: The second example isn't defining constants, it's calling methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `constants` on `Class` object as well as shown below

```
class Sex
    Male = 1
    Female = 2
end

p Sex.constants # will return [:Male, :Female]
```

The reason it will work is `Module` happens to be base class of `Class`

```
p Sex.class.ancestors
#=> [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Sex
  Male = 1
  Female = 2
end
```

This defines two constants on the `Sex` class. `Sex` is an instance of `Class` and the superclass of `Class` is `Module`:

```
c = Sex.class  # => Class
c.superclass   # => Module
```

You already know how to get an array of constant names as symbols from a module and since this method is inherited, you can just call it on the `Sex` class:

```
Sex.constants  # => [:Male, :Female]
```

I'm not sure about your second example. Assuming you mean this ([read about `class << self`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505067/class-self-idiom-in-ruby)):

```
class Sex
  class << self
    Male = 1
    Female = 2
  end
end
```

This defines two constants on the [singleton class](http://readruby.chengguangnan.com/classes#singleton) of the `Sex` class. The method [`Object#singleton_class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class) returns the singleton class of an object. After that `methods`, `instance_variables` or `constants` can be called in the usual way:

```
Sex.singleton_class.constants  # => [:Male, :Female]
```

Comment: `Sex.constants  # => [:Male, :Female]` regardless of which of the two ways you do it. Is there a difference?

Comment: This answer is correct, but there is less concrete. Thank you for answer!